# Hilbert $C^*$ Modules, dense submodules

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

I read a paper in which the author uses the propetry that if $A$ is a submodule of a

Hilbert $C^\ast$ module ($C$ is a $C^*$ algebra) such that

$A^\bot=0$ then $A$ is dense. I don't know how to prove it since in a gneral Hilbert module over a $C^*$ algebra $(A^\bot)^\bot$ is greater than $Closure(A)$ and the standard Hilbert space proof does not work.

The paper in question is:
 UNBOUNDED OPERATORS ON HILBERT C∗-MODULES OVER C∗-ALGEBRAS OF COMPACT OPERATORS by Guljas
you can find on the web.

Comment: In general, I agree with the answer by MTS.  However, if you look at the paper you mention, then it _only_ considers modules over the algebra of compact operators, and such things are rather special.  See the 2nd paragraph of the paper: "These modules are characterized by the property that each closed submodule is orthogonally complemented or orthogonally closed"

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, I don't believe the statement is true in general.  For example, take $C = C(X)$ for some $X$.  Take your $C^*$-module to be $C$ itself with the standard inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = f^*g$.  Let $x_0 \in X$ and define 
$$ A =  \{ f \in C \mid f(x_0) =0 \}.  $$
Then $A^\perp = 0$ but $A$ is not dense in $C$.